# How to get the ID of the parent comment (facebook Graph API)?

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

When sending a request

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/123456898765432/comments?access_token=TOKEN&pretty=1&filter=stream&limit=1&summary=1

I get an answer

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2015-06-17T10:32:04+0000",
         "from": {
            "name": "First Name",
            "id": "12345678987654"
         },
         "message": "Message",
         "can_remove": true,
         "like_count": 0,
         "user_likes": false,
         "id": "123456898765432_123456789765433"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "...",
         "after": "..."
      },
   },
   "summary": {
      "order": "chronological",
      "total_count": 2532
   }
}
```

But if the comment of the second level, I do not know the ID of the parent comment, and I can not answer it programmatically.

Maybe there are some arguments that can be specified, and additional data comment?

I found that there is still an argument metadata = 1
But it shows additional information counter on the object, and there is also no parent ID

Comment: According to docs, the comment should have a `parent` field.

Comment: I gave an example of a working code.
Alas, I still could not get the ID of the parent

Comment: This might be an error in our documentation, I would file a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs, providing the exact documentation mentioning this and a Graph API session proving otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and it seems that you can get the parent comment.

### request

> 111791572258237_803009099803144?fields=comments.filter(stream).limit(50){message,id,from,parent}
>
> (the ACCESS_TOKEN was omitted)

### response

```
{
  "message": "Sim, está acontecendo com várias pessoas. A Valve vai arrumar logo, provavelmente",
  "id": "803009099803144_803075496463171",
  "from": {
    "name": "Jonathan Gouvea",
    "id": "1218897258138073"
  },
  "parent": {
    "created_time": "2016-01-28T19:58:39+0000",
    "from": {
      "name": "César Rodryguês",
      "id": "552640601571460"
    },
    "message": "Dota ta fechando o de vcs quando vai entra na partida ?",
    "id": "803009099803144_803068649797189"
  }
},
```